# how to make array from classes java

Tags: java, arrays

I want from this

```
GuiClass marek = new GuiClass(1,"Marek");
GuiClass peter = new GuiClass(2,"Peter");
GuiClass tomas = new GuiClass(3,"Tomas");
GuiClass julo = new GuiClass(4,"Julo");
```

make an Strig array

```
String [] Gui;
Gui = new String[] {"marek","peter","tomas","julo"}
```

and after pass this array to the function,

Comment: It is not clear what you have and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Not very clear... but you can try implementing toString() method in GuiClass and then:
Gui = new String[] {marek.toString(),peter.toString(),tomas.toString(),julo.toString()}

Comment: It's possible, assuming `GuiClass` has a getter for the second parameter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you want to create array of your class you made.

try this code as example:

```
public class test {

    ClassList cl[] = new ClassList[5];

    public test(){
        cl[0] = new ClassList("index 1", "name1");
        cl[1] = new ClassList("index 2", "name2");
        cl[2] = new ClassList("index 3", "name3");
        cl[3] = new ClassList("index 4", "name4");
        cl[4] = new ClassList("index 5", "name5");

        for(int i = 0; i<cl.length; i++){
            System.out.println(cl[i].getA()+" "+cl[i].getB());
        }
    }
     public static void main(String args[]){
         new test();

     }
}

class ClassList{
    String a;
    String b;
    public ClassList(String a,String b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    public String getA(){   return a;   }
    public String getB(){   return b;   }
}
```

Comment: Thnxs a lot works for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java 8 Streams API :

```
String[] Gui = Stream.of(marek, peter, tomas, julo)
                     .map (GuiClass::getName) // assuming GuiClass has 
                                              // getName method
                     .toArray();
```

In the more general case, if you have an array of GuiClass (i.e. `GuiClass[]`), you can pass that array to `Stream.of` instead.

Comment: This is potentially not useful for the OP. He didn't even understand how an array works and you're coming up with a sophisticated `Stream` class etc. IMHO, OP should learn the basics first, so the answer should be how to write a `for` loop.

Comment: @Thomas It seems the OP did find it useful.

Comment: Sure, it helped him get his code work but he still doesn't understand why.

Comment: i am compiling in eclipse jre7 .. .

Answer (score -1):

Yes, what you mentioned is possible. But later, if you plan to add more objects of `GuiClass` to the array, then it is better option to override `toString()` method in `GuiClass` so that you don't have to always use variable names (i.e. "marek","peter","tomas","julo" etc.) as values in array. You can instead use something like:

```
new String[] {marek.toString(), peter.toString(), someFutureVariable.toString(),... };
```

which is more maintainable.

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. Please learn how to format the code in your answers.